# breaking out of while loop

Tags: python-3

Trying to stop a light blinking "while" loop by querying the position of a gamepad joystick.  Can't seem to continuously query while in the loop and break out of the inner loop.  Can you suggest fix?
Code so far is:

```py
        elif int(controller_input['ABS_Y']) > 140:
            left_thumb_joystick_d()
            while int(controller_input['ABS_Y']) > 140:
                hd_lights_on()
                tail_lights_on()
                #beeper_on()
                sleep(.5)
                hd_lights_off()
                tail_lights_off()
                #beeper_off()
                sleep(.5)
                gamepad_update()
```

The gamepad_update code reads:
def gamepad_update():
# Code execution stops at the following line until gamepad event occurs.
events = get_gamepad()
return_code = 'No Match'
for event in events:
event_test = controller_input.get(event.code, 'No Match')
if event_test != 'No Match':
controller_input[event.code] = event.state
return_code = event.code
else:
return_code = 'No Match'

```
    return return_code
```

Comment: Not Pi specific.  A Python tutorial is a good place to start.

Comment: you just need to do something inside the while loop to update controller_input['ABS_Y'].  if it sits at the old value, it stays > 140

Comment: I have tried adding the "control_code = gamepad_update()" and update the js input to no avail.  Position that on top of the while loop and under the while loop  and then an "if" statement to query, but no help.

Comment: Why did you leave out the code that you mentioned in your comment?

Comment: Look up what `break`/`continue`/`pass` statements do in python...